# replace a tag ion index.html on build using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following script

```
# Source the .env file
set -a
source ./apps/core/.build.env
set +a

file_path=/apps/core/src/index.html

if [ "$NX_ALLOW_TRACKING" == "true" ]; then
  sed -i '' "s@<!--GTAG_PLACEHOLDER_SCRIPT-->@blabla@g" $file_path
else
  sed -i '' "s|<!--GTAG_PLACEHOLDER_SCRIPT-->||g" $file_pathh
fi
```

that basically replace `GTAG_PLACEHOLDER_SCRIPT` with `blabla`

I would like to run it in a pipeline in order to generate the correct tracking based on the environment.

this script tho return

> sed: can't read s@@blabla@g: No such file or directory

I don't get why. If I add a debug like

`cd "apps/core/src/" ls > ls.log cat ls.log`

I do see that `index.html` is present, and the path is correct, yet, the replacement always say not found.

I also tried

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
file_path="$SCRIPT_DIR/src/index.html"
```

but still same

sed: can't read s@@blabla@g: No such file or directory

Comment: The `-i ''` part is BSD-only, it won't work with GNU sed.

Comment: Right. Options with optional arguments in GNU don't read from the next argument. Try removing the empty argument, adding some `-e`  or placing `-i` at the end of the arguments list.